Does stack work differently in assembly than how it works in C?
I just started learning assembly code. As far as I understand, when a functions calls in assembly code, the main variables are stored to stack from registers and stored back to registers after function returns. That is the way how stack works, preventing the saved registers to be overwritten and save the main program variables. But in C convention, stack is a memory place where local variables of functions are stored temporarily. These two conventions contradicts in my head so that I'm confused.
Can you help me if i misunderstood some concepts?

Nothing to contradict here, many different things can be stored on the stack at once.

The stack is used for both things, but the compiler handles the saving of registers for you, so you don't notice that when programming in C.

I don't think C even defines that locals must go on a stack. There is nothing stack like about local variables except maybe their lifetime since you can access them randomly.

@Jester I guess C requires that something equivalent to a stack exists to allow recursive function calls. Of course, everything can be optimized away where it is not required.

@Jester C merely defines what automatic storage is, but not how it is implemented.  Your system could have a linked list instead of a stack!

The C language does not expose a call or runtime stack to the C language programmer. Instead, C provides for local variables and parameters all of which will survive a function call as needed.  So the comparison is somewhat erroneous.  There is a mapping that the C compiler does from C variables to physical storage, which includes registers and stack memory.

Further, there is a notion of return address, hidden in C, that allows for functions to return to whomever called them.  And also, in assembly/machine code, there is a thread stack (hidden in C) provided to support recursion and storage of variables, temporaries (also hidden in C), and return addresses as needed.

@fuz - an example of this would be IBM 360 | 370. Instead of a stack, a save area is used to save registers. The caller is responsible for allocating the save area,  the calling convention uses R13 to point to the save area, R14 for return address, R15 for the base address of the functions code. For nested calls, the save value for R13 in the save area acts at a backward link to prior saved area, like a reversed linked list.

The method of passing arguments to function depends upon the underlying system and the programming language.
In assembly, you can generally use registers, stack space, or static memory locations for variables. You only indicate using registers which is probably the source of your misconception.
Programming languages generally have no concept of registers (although C has a register keyword). The compiler may place variables in registers for optimization.
Typically a compiled or assembly language function pushes the registers it modifies on the stack upon entry, and allocates any stack space needed for other local variables.

MOVAL -AMOUNT_OF_STACK_SPACE_NEEDED(SP), (SP)

Upon exit, it pops them back into registerst.
There are a lot of variations on this that depend upon the underlying hardware. Some systems have dedicate registers for passing arguments. The convension on system systems is to use certain registers for arguments.
